# Same Wpf app on server and client possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, tcp, webserver

I run an application (can run as console app or windows service) that frequently makes updated data available either through tdf data blocks, callbacks, or other means such as publishing to RedisDB channels. (I will chose only one means out of the three mentioned depending on which framework to go with in the end).

I like those updates reflected in a Wpf frontend gui application that runs on the same machine as the core application that outputs said data. At the same time I want to be able to run the same wpf application on a client machine that receives said data on a client machine that may not even reside in the same network but connect through tcp, browser, or other means over the Internet.

What is the most optimal framework that accomplishes that and please keep in mind that I want to implement the mvvm pattern within the wpf application. The data that the wpf application will need are chart data point updates, grid updates, and other status messages. The wpf application should also be able to submit data back to the core application through human interaction through controls within the wpf application.

Any recommendations which layers and frameworks would most optimally solve my problem? I want to stick to a wpf application, not silver light and not asp.net. I could consider running the wpf app within a browser but it has to run within google chrome not only ms ie.even the wpf frontend on the same machine as the core app can run within a browser if that is the optimal solution though I would prefer an installed windows wpf application.

Any recommendations and guidance?

Thanks

Comment: My recommendation would be to narrow your question to a specific programming question that we could help with here. I'd think a web application would actually be a better fit, and if you still want WPF, look at http://signalr.net/ (using the .NET client).

Comment: Why not just WCF Duplex via TCP? It will allow you to send messages in the fashion `Server <-> Client`. And it does not have special requirements in the client machine.

Comment: because WCF seems overkill. I focus on small messages, which however may be sent several times per second. I also look to stream serialized objects. What keeps me away from WCF is all that heavy class and method decoration that I find quite useless. All the server needs to know for a request/response type of message is what message type the client expects as response. Why all those decorations is beyond me. But then I am pretty new to it and may miss something. Its just solutions such as ServiceStack get away without decorations.